# Add Social Login to my current Django project

Tags: django, authentication, django-socialauth

I have an email/password signup/login flow in my Django project.
I want to add LinkedIn login flow to my project.
I would like to use the current User DB table for LinkedIn login.
What I want is when a user logs in using LinkedIn, I want to get the user information and save it to the current User DB table, login and redirect to the home page.

Please help me!

The important thing is that when a user logs in using LinkedIn, I want to customize the user data in the backend and store it in the current User DB table.